# How to find duplicates including the first occurrence

Tags: r, duplicate-detection

I have this vector

```
vector <- c("www.one","www.two","www.one","www.three")
```

and I want to find all duplicates, including the first occurrence of the duplicated value. If I do

```
dup <- duplicated(vector)
```

I get

```
dup
# [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

while I need to get

```
# [1] TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can call `duplicated` twice, looking for duplicates from the front and from the back.

```
duplicated(vector) | duplicated(vector, fromLast=TRUE)
# [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's another way:

```
Rgames> foo<-c('a','b','d','f','a','b','b','q')
Rgames> which(foo%in%foo[which(duplicated(foo))])
[1] 1 2 5 6 7
```